# How to remove TuxCut app from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dpkg

I've installed `tuxcut` but it's in different language.
I've tried removing it using `dpkg` but didn't worked so I downloaded a English version and tried installing it. But I got this error.
Any help to remove that arabic Tuxcut..??

```
cybercam@cybercam:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i tuxcut_5.0_all.deb
(Reading database ... 176367 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace tuxcut 5.0 (using tuxcut_5.0_all.deb) ...
rm: cannot remove `/usr/bin/run-tuxcut': No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
rm: cannot remove `/usr/bin/run-tuxcut': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing tuxcut_5.0_all.deb (--install):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
tuxcut_5.0_all.deb
```

Tuxcut is running at 'Python' `opt/TuxCut/run.py`

Answer (score 1):

The version you had earlier also comes with English. Run tuxcut as it was(in Arabic), select your interface. So far everything would still be in Arabic. Now you should see a menu bar on top. It's above everything and has four drop down buttons aligned towards the right. Click on the third one from the right. It'll drop down to give you exactly one expandable button. Clicking on that will give you two options, one of which will already be checked. That one's for Arabic. And you guessed it, the other one's for English. Changes won't take effect till you restart tuxcut.

As for the errors. Using dpkg will result in the errors you are getting. Uninstall tuxcut using `sudo apt-get remove tuxcut`. Now re-install using dpkg the same way you were trying. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut
sudo apt-get purge tuxcut
```

I was also getting same error.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How to remove TuxCut app from Ubuntu 12.1O 
http://www.iasptk.com/15825-ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.